# Реализация встроенного джойстика в Андроид

Tags: java, android

Скажите, как можно реализовать в Андроид на Java управление с помощью встроенного джойстика (как в левом нижнем углу экрана)?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Лично я делал это с помощью `libGDX`.И есть туториал на эту тему [ссылка на источник](http://suvitruf.ru/2012/11/25/2615/).

Comment: Скажите, а как можно без джойстика, стандартными средствами, реализовать движение "змейки"? так чтобы куда пальцем ведем, туда она и двигается

Comment: @Dagget, К примеру есть метод `onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)` - дальше используем `event` и через условие проверяем нужное нам событие `event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_HOVER_MOVE`.